# SVG image coloured in three sections

Tags: css, svg

I need to dynamically colour an SVG image on the website. The website will complete some calculations, based on the users' input, and, rather than producing a pie chart, the results have to displayed as different colours on the image. No issues implementing the calculations, however, I have no experience of working with SVGs - the best way I found so far was to use the below:

```
<defs>
  <linearGradient id="myGradient" gradientTransform="rotate(0)">
    <stop offset="33%"  stop-color="gold" stop-opacity="1" />
    <stop offset="66%" stop-color="red" stop-opacity="1"/>
    <stop offset="80%" stop-color="blue" stop-opacity="1"/>
  </linearGradient>
</defs>
```

This gives me almost the result I am looking for:
[image]

However, I need to prevent colours merging into each other.

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: make 2 color stop for the red and place them at 33% and 80% to avoid the gradient effecy

Comment: You, sir, are a star!